# How to monitor database connection in java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jakarta-ee

i have created web application using java. In that i am using tomcat server and SQL server. I need to implement watch dog service for monitoring database connection and server connection. I mean if database is not connecting or tomcat server is down then i need to write a code for send a alerting mail to my mail id.

pls someone help me...

Comment: write while loop that every minute (few seconds mb) try to connect sql server(and send some query's to test if need) and simple http request to tomcat, then if something is wrong send email

Comment: I'd recommend using a reliable 3rd party service like SiteScope, or if you need more info, New Relic...

Comment: First of all, maybe you are working on the symptoms. You should find out why the DB and Tomcat could crash and fix that problem. If you really need to monitor, have a look at existing solutions, e.g.: http://mmonit.com/monit/

Comment: i will check it and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate thread to monitor the DB connection. While starting  the server invoke that thread. If db connection failed means send mail from that threat.

Example :

```
        boolean isDBConnected,isServerConnected;
        while(true){                
            isDBConnected=checkDBConnection();
            isServerConnected=checkServerStatus();
            if(isDBConnected && isServerConnected){
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }else{
                sendMail();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur idea.. i will implement it and let you know